# Matching all files ending with a certain extension with a shell glob (say, all files ending with .sh)

Tags: shell-script, wildcards

I desire to match all files ending with a certain extension with a shell glob.

In this case I desire to target all files ending with the `.sh` extension, which are bourne files I execute with the Bash shell after putting a "shebang" (like `#!/bin/bash`) at their first line.

This is, for example, a cron command I have:

```
0 0 * * * "$HOME"/public_html/cron_daily/myfile.sh 2>/dev/null
```

Instead myfile.sh I need to target all files in that dir, ending with a `.sh` extension.

Is the following code correct?

```
0 0 * * * "$HOME"/public_html/cron_daily/*$.sh 2>/dev/null
```

### Update

I think this is good when using a glob:

```
*.{sh}
```

Comment: I thought “You’d just use `*.sh` to match all files with a `.sh` extension.” was clear enough... `*.sh` is the glob you use to match files ending with `.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way, since they will be combined into one command line.

```
for scr in "$HOME"/public_html/cron_daily/*.sh ; do "$scr" 2> /dev/null; done
```

Comment: I believe it isn't a great deal but writing `file` instead `scr` could be clearer and more accurate as it is a file containing a script. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

You’d just use `*.sh` to match all files with a `.sh` extension. (Adding the path as appropriate.)

However this won’t have the result you’re after. Look at `run-parts` to run multiple scripts from `cron`:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/run-parts "$HOME"/public_html/cron_daily/ 2>/dev/null
```

(This will run all executables in `.../public_html/cron_daily`, not just `.sh` files. By the way, are you sure it’s a good idea to keep cron scripts under `public_html`? Is that directory being served by your web server?)

Comment: I think only website directories are served from that directory but maybe not.