# A filename has an asterisk for some reason - it won't be changed and content not executed

Tags: bash, centos, cron, mv, cpanel

I use CentOS shared server environment with Bash.

```
ll "$HOME"/public_html/cron_daily/
```

brings:

```
./
../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user group 181 Jul 11 11:32 wp_cli.sh*
```

I don't know why the filename has an asterisk in the end. I don't recall adding it and when I tried to change it I got this output:

```
[~/public_html]# mv cron_daily/wp_cli.sh* cron_daily/wp_cli.sh
+ mv cron_daily/wp_cli.sh cron_daily/wp_cli.sh
mv: `cron_daily/wp_cli.sh' and `cron_daily/wp_cli.sh' are the same file
```

This error might indicate why my Cpanel cronjob failed:

[image]

Did I do anything wrong when changing the file or when running the Cpanel cron command? Because both operations seem to fail.

Comment: I don't know if this can happen on Linux, but I recall a few cases on, I'm thinking, UNIX and MSDOS, where such "illegal" names had actually been created, presumably as a result of using a machine-language interface to manipulate/rename files, vs using the normal command and HL language interfaces.

Comment: @HotLicks The only illegal names (at least on Linux) are an empty string, and a name with a slash (`/`) or null byte. You can make files with asterisks no-prob by quoting the asterisk or escaping it like this `touch wp_cli.sh\*`.

Comment: Similar: https://superuser.com/questions/178786/what-does-the-asterisk-mean-after-a-filename-when-you-type-ls-l

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The asterisk is not actually part of the filename.  You are seeing it because the file is executable and your alias for `ll` includes the `-F` flag:

> -F
>
> > Display a slash ('/') immediately after each pathname that is a directory, an asterisk ('*') after each that is executable, an
> >                  at sign ('@') after each symbolic link, an equals sign (`=') after each socket, a percent sign ('%') after each whiteout, and a
> >                  vertical bar ('|') after each that is a FIFO.

---

As Kusalananda mentioned you can't glob all scripts in a directory with cron like that.  With run-parts, you can call `"$HOME"/public_html/cron_daily/` to execute all scripts in the directory (not just .sh) or loop through them as mentioned in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/454749/237982).

Comment: Additionally, the cronjob fails because you can't execute all script in a directory like that. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454749/matching-all-files-ending-with-a-certain-extension-with-a-shell-glob-say-all-f

Comment: Uh, how would `"$HOME"/public_html/cron_daily/` run all scripts in the directory? `cron` will only run one command, and it won't use shell expansion. The easiest solution for OP would be to create a wrapper script that does `for script in "$HOME"/public_html/cron_daily/*.sh; do $script; done`, and then call the wrapper from cron.

Comment: @nneonneo Debian/Ubuntu already have [run-parts](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/debianutils/run-parts.8.en.html), which does this, maybe other distributions have something similar?

Comment: @nneonneo: Updated

Answer (score 11):

[Jesse_b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/237982/jesse-b) already answered the question, but I think it's worth to address some potential misconceptions.

The shell has characters that have special meaning under some specific conditions. For example: `|` is used in pipelines, `>` in redirections, `\` to escape characters, etc. Those characters are not interpreted literally by the shell, so that's why when you do `echo foo>bar`, `foo>bar` won't be printed to your terminal, but `foo` will be redirected to the `bar` file.

Fortunately, the shell also has a mechanism which makes these characters to lose their special meaning: quoting. In POSIX shells, [there are 3 quoting mechanisms](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02):

- **Backslash `\`:** preserves the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a `<newline>`.
- **Double-quotes `"..."`:** preserves the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters `` ` ``, `$`, and `\`.
- **Single-quotes `'...'`:** preserves the literal value of each character within the single-quotes, no exceptions.

So, following the previous example, if we wanted to print `foo>bar` literally, we could have done:

- `echo foo\>bar`
- `echo "foo>bar"`
- `echo 'foo>bar'`

The asterisk `*` is one of those special characters, it is part of the [pattern matching notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) and is used for [filename expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03). In other words, commands such as `echo *.txt` will replace the pattern with the files that the pattern matches.

In your case, `cron_daily/wp_cli.sh*` only matches `cron_daily/wp_cli.sh`, so `mv` sees 2 identical arguments and complains about it. That's fine because there's no `cron_daily/wp_cli.sh*` file. But if you had had an actual `cron_daily/wp_cli.sh*` file and more files that could be matched by the pattern, `mv` would have fail.

Consider the following scenario:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 jul 14 12:00 file*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 jul 14 12:00 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 jul 14 12:00 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 jul 14 12:00 file3
```

If I try to rename `file*` without using quotes:

```
$ mv file* new_file
mv: target 'new_file' is not a directory
```

That's because these are the arguments that `mv` receives, thus `new_file` is expected to be a directory:

```
$ printf '[%s]\n' file* new_file
[file*]
[file1]
[file2]
[file3]
[new_file]
```

To successfully rename `file*`, I need to quote that argument:

```
$ mv 'file*' new_file
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 jul 14 12:00 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 jul 14 12:00 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 jul 14 12:00 file3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 jul 14 12:00 new_file
```